# Avoiding the null values to replace 0 values in report

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005 BOXIR2.

My doubt, from universe table there is an eventcode having different types of codes like Enquiry,FollowUp,LostofSales,Contact,etc

I make a measure that is from object properties formula count(Tablename.EventCode)save and export it, when I used this EventCode in Webireport, it show values for paricular EventCode, but zero values are not read it show null blank as below example .

I WANT TO GET THE ZERO VALUES FOR WHICH IT IS IN BLANK(NULL).

```
count(Tablename.EventCode)
Enquiry,FollowUp,LostofSales,Contact
10 20 15
5 12 5
6 4 3
```

Can u please help me how to get get zero values for null,Formula

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but I think you may be looking for ISNULL()

```
SELECT ISNULL(table_name.column_name, 0)
```

will return 0 if table_name.column_name is null

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting NULLs when performing an aggregate, it's probably because one of elements is NULL. All you need to do is coalesce those entries to a known value (such as zero).

```
SELECT COUNT(COALESCE(Tablename.EventCode, 0)) FROM Tablename
```

Comment: `COUNT` never returns `NULL`. I'm not clear what the OP's question is.